# I can't upload my Unity game in the PlayStore, because It says the uploaded .aab file is empty

Tags: unity-game-engine

Recently, I finished a project in Unity and I am trying to release it in the playstore (this is my first time), but whenever I try to upload it in the app bundles it gives the following error:

[image]

And when I look at the properties of this .aab file, it says that the file contains zero bytes of information, even though I just build my entire Unity project on it.

[image]

When I open Unity, I get the following errors, which I've looked up, but I couldn't find a proper answer with relevance to my project.

[image]

These are my build settings:

[image]

I followed a tutorial video, which says that it's relevant in 2022, and I followed every step, but it still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try building the game with **EXPORT PROJECT** option and build the app with Android Studio... I'm also having a lot of issues exporting with Unity 3D.

Export the project > Drag the new folder into Android Studio > Export Project (Select if APK or not)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I only find the option to export packages of the project, and not the project itself, where can I find this function?

Comment: Select Export Project option on Build Settings... It's showing the option in the last image